# ASP.NET Url rewrite maps

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, configuration-files

I'm trying to get my head around url rewriting in ASP.NET. I have two rewritemaps.config files (rewritemaps1.config and rewritemaps2.config) I had to split these up in two since the config file size would be too large for IIS to handle.

Now, in web.config, I need to include these two maps for the rewriter, but I can only have one `<rewritemaps>` in the config.

My web.config looks like this:

```
<rewrite>                
    <rewriteMaps configSource="rewritemaps1.config"></rewriteMaps>

    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect rule1 for Redirects">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{Redirects:{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent"/>
      </rule>

    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Is there any way to "include" both configs? :-)

Thanks in advance.